# My web page doesn't resize for small devices properly

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/IrvingG/pen/adqaXg

The URL above is my portfolio which I'm working with through FreeCodeCamp there you can see my code for HTML and CSS. I am having difficulties with how the page is viewed through small devices. The pages get smaller but the contents disappear underneath. When I view the page on a desktop it looks how I want for now but not on a mobile. I'm not sure what to do with contact section but it's not my main concern. I would like some help or ideas on how to fix my page or what I did wrong for it to behave that way. Thank you so much in advanced.

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Irving Gonzalez</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#slide2">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide2">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide3">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!----- SLIDES START --->
  <div class="jumbotron" id="slide1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#slide3" role="button">Projects</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slide2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="text-center" id="about">About</h1>
          <p class="text-justify lead text-muted" id="aboutMe">
            Hi there! My name is Irving Gonzalez and I am a <b>Computer Science</b> student at <b>John Jay College of Criminal Justice</b>. Currently, I am working towards becoming a Full Stack Web Developer with the help of the curriculum from <b>freeCodeCamp</b>            as well as other self-taught web services. I have a passion for innovation, deviation, technology, and languages.
            <br>
            <br> Below are some of the projects I've completed.
            <p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
          <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/rm7495.jpg" alt="design thing" class="img-rounded img-responsive" id="aboutimage">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slide3">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Works</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-offset-1 col-sm-3">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/IrvingG/full/BjVvjb/" class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/9u8ytv.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Random Quotes</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-2 col-sm-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Basic Calculator</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-2 col-sm-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-offset-1 col-sm-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-2 col-sm-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-2 col-sm-3">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="workThumbnails"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/under-construction/512/coming_soon-256.png" alt="Future Project">
            <div class="caption text-center">
              <h4>Future Project</h4></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slide4">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <!--               ether move these to the bottom or delete them                  -->
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-offset-3">
          <a href="mailto:irv.jgonz@gmail.com" alt="irv.jgonz@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/irvgonz" alt="FreeCodeCamp" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-fire fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"><a href="http://github.com/irvgonz" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/irving.gonzalez.1466" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"><a href="https://twitter.com/g0_irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class "col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
          <h2>GET IN TOUCH</h2>
          <p>Do you have any questions, comments, or simply want to say Hello?
            <br>Send me a message through the social media above.
            <br>I'll be more than happy to help you!
          </p>
          <address>
  <strong>Irving Gonzalez</strong><br>
 1234 MadeUp place<br>
  New York, NY 10040<br>
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-1x"></i> (123) 456-7890<br>
  <a href="mailto:irv.jgonz@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x"> Irv.jgonz@gmail.com</i></a>
</address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
        <p>@ 2016 Irving Gonzalez</p>
      </div>
      <!--
      <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
        <a href="mailto:irv.jgonz@gmail.com" alt="irv.jgonz@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/irvgonz" alt="FreeCodeCamp" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fire fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="http://github.com/irvgonz" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/irving.gonzalez.1466" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/g0_irving" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
          This will put the social media at the bottom-->
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
#about{
  color: #404040;
}

#aboutimage{
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px grey;
}

#aboutMe{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding:15px;
  border:rounded;
}

#workThumbnails{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px grey;
}

#slide2 .container{
  position: relative; 
  right: 50px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#slide4 .row a{
  /*This changes the color of the links do not delete*/
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* this is for the navbar links on the bottom in case i want to switch it.
.navbar .container a{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
*/

.jumbotron {
  background: url("http://i64.tinypic.com/33nvoft.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  color: #fff;
  height: 670px;
  padding: 200px 0 260px 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

#slide2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333333;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
}

#slide3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333333;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide4 {
  background: url("http://i66.tinypic.com/x6eyw.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top:25px; 
  color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thats the expected behavior right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS

```
#slide3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333333;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will extend your main content slide to the height of the available window.

Answer (score 1):

When you gradually reduce the width of the window I can see part of the text in the "About" section is being overlapped. Try adding this to your CSS.

```
#slide2 div.container div.row
{
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, is this the way to reference things inside? I was confused on how to do so, this looks very helpful. " #slide2 div.container div.row "

Comment: In this specific case it could be "#slide2 .container .row" or even "#slide2 .row".

Answer (score 1):

Your content is dissapearing because you set the slides to have a height and then set the overflow to hidden.  So the contents are not dissapearing beneath anything they are being cut off at the height that you set your slides.

Comment: You're right, I didn't have the right words while explaining. I did know that the height was the culprit but did not know how to work around it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have used too many column grid classes that are really unnecessary here mate. All you need is to use .col-md-6 on both sections below the projects slide i.e, in #slide2. Also, remove the padding-right and padding-left properties from the .container class in #slide2. Use similar edits for the rest of the page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ashwin buddy you are wrong. In order to get the page layout properly on all size devices we must specify how many columns width to take on each device size. I dont see that being the problem

Comment: is there a general rule for columns, I read the bootstrap documentation and somewhat it makes sense to me. But is there a limit or something I'm not aware? I'm not an expert still grasping html and css.